# exact use of "Forbidden File path" of the Jenkins Gerrit Trigger plugin

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

The Jenkins Gerrit Trigger Plugin has a button "Add Forbidden File path" but actually there is not too much documentation avaiable for it.
So what is the exact behavior of it?

- Does it inhibit the trigger if **one** of the changed files match?
- Or does it inhibit the trigger if **all** of the changed files match?
  (in other words: only matching files have changed)
- I suppose it "overrides" a match of "Add File Path", doesn't it?
- does it work for directory names only or down to file names?

This leads mit to the question if:
"File Path"= `^((?!_abc)(?!_def).)*$`
behaves equal to:
"Forbidden File Path"= `^.*_abc$|^.*_def$` ?

Comment: seems that there not too much Jenkins/Gerrit users around here...

Comment: I did some testing (although it's quite time consuming due to long build times) but I don't have a satisfying answer up to now. With the "File path" method I get triggers I don't want to get. With the "Forbidden File Path" method I miss triggers I want to get...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs my needs should be adressed with V2.16.0 of the Plugin (see [JENKINS-30620](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30620)) - the new option "**Disable Strict Forbidden File Verification**" should be used for this.
In the help it says:

> - Enabling this option will allow an event to trigger a build if the    event contains BOTH one or more wanted file paths AND one or more
>     forbidden file paths.
> - In other words, with this option, the build    will not get triggered if the change contains only forbidden files,    otherwise it
>     will get triggered.

So I took a day of testing **but it doesn't seem to work at my site**.
But at least I **got it working** via the "Add File Path" parameter, thanks to the information that was postet in [JENKINS-19891](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19891%20JENKINS-19891):

> *However, since the commit always contains **COMMIT_MSG** file, it will match the regex and triggers the build.*

So I added the commit message file to my regexes which finally gives me the correct results.

**Example:** `^((?!\/COMMIT_MSG|cunit|_abc|_def[\/\.]).)*$`
...for ignoring changes in files who's name (including path) contains any of "cunit", "_abc", "_def." or "_def/"

Answer (score 3):

#### One or many files

> Does it inhibit the trigger if one of the changed files match?
> Or does it inhibit the trigger if all of the changed files match?
> (in other words: only matching files have changed)

According [commit message](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/commit/4337255ba9c272ed668ca71c632c486119a1aaf4) trigger is inhibit if any file is matched.

> This forbidden file allows the project not to trigger if any forbidden
> file has been impacted.

#### Overriding

> I suppose it "overrides" a match of "Add File Path", doesn't it?

Yes. `Add Forbidden file path` has higher priority than `Add File path`.

#### Working for ...

> does it work for directory names only or down to file names?

For both. But it is hard to add empty folder.

#### Question about behavior

> This leads mit to the question if:
>
> "File Path"= ^((?!_abc)(?!_def).)*$
>
> behaves equal to:
>
> "Forbidden File Path"= ^.*_abc$|^.*_def$ ?

Probably you made a mistake: `^((?!_abc)(?!_def).)*$` instead of `^.*(?!_abc)(?!_def)$`. Because in first case you compare right from start (`^`) and your quantifier (`*`) repeats whole expression, not a `.`.

In second case we have a different behavior for two or more files. Because

1. `Add File path` starts build if any of them found. But `Add Forbidden File path` inhibits build if any of file found.
2. Also you need to fill `Add File path` with `**` at least to start work `Add Forbidden File path`. `Add Forbidden File path` doesn't work if `Add File path` is empty.

Comment: Many thanks for this very useful answer! So (what I should have guessed) it does what it says - and the feature that would make it really comfortable for me would be named "Add Ignored File path" (but doesn't exist).
I will doublecheck my regexes...

Comment: Regarding the last point ("Add File path" may not be empty): this means that the "Add Forbidden File path" doesn't inhibit any trigger if "Add File path" is empty, does ist? A very notably fact, indeed!

Comment: Regarding the regexes: I must confess that I never fully understood the negative lookahead. I did some testing on www.regexr.com but it gives me correct results with ^((?!_abc)(?!_def).)*$

Comment: ad 2.) this should be fixed with V2.15.2 of the plugin (according to https://github.com/jenkinsci/gerrit-trigger-plugin/pull/251). So it should also work if "Add File path" is empty.